Need advice on cutting replacement plywood that is not square
I am removing white paint from cabinets as they are attached to the wall.  The material used on the back is low quality wood so I can't get the paint off well.  I bought 1/4" plywood to cut and fit in the back.  I can then stain and varnish.  Do I need to make a pattern to follow to cut the piece correctly?  It is not square, so makes it difficult
Thanks.

This is an open shelf, so no door to hide the back.

As usual, more information would be helpful.  In addition to a picture.  1) is one of the sides trully vertical  2) what's holding the shelf to the wall (is it inside or outside the verticals).  Since the back board you want to install will be totally inside the shelf/cabinet, it won't be supporting the cabinet - how do you intend to support the new back piece?  How, if at all, do you intent to hide the edges of this back piece? What type of plywood - hardwood vs AC or BC grade plywood.

You are understanding what I am describing.  This is a kitchen cabinet that has been converted to a shelf to mount an above range microwave.  It is attached to the wall.  I was thinking I could just glue the new piece to the existing back.  I am hoping to cut the new piece close enough to just use wood filler, then stain and varnish.  My plywood is Lauan.  I also considered trimming it out with narrow quarter round.  It wouldn't be too visible.  The back isn't totally square.  It is good in the top left corner, but how do I adjust for other corners?

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. "I bought 1/4" plywood to cut and fit in the back. I can then stain and varnish." Best of luck with that — plywood often doesn't stain as evenly as hoped and low-quality lauan plywood... take it as a given that the colour won't come out quite as you envisage. Recommend you do a sample, working exactly as you intend to and see what you think.

"The back isn't totally square. It is good in the top left corner, but how do I adjust for other corners?" Ideally get the outline perfect by directly marking from the cabinet onto your material. If you absolutely cannot do this, then get the diagonal measures very accurately using "pinch sticks" AKA "pinch rods", which are arguably the way to measure internal diagonals. Then it's simply a matter of sawing to shape and, if necessary, refining using plane, rasp or file, or sandpaper.

Note that when built, the cabinet should have been square. The right answer is probably to push it back to being square and then for the new back to that.

It seems R M Miller plans to use hardwood plywood to cover an unsightly back of a shelf which used to be a kitchen cabinet. No evaluation is provided here for the structural nor electrical ability of the shelf to handle a microwave oven. It is also reported that the back area where the plywood is to be installed is four sided however only the top and bottom are parallel, in short, the sides are not square to the top nor bottom.
I would cut a piece of plywood to approximately fit the opening.  Rather than attempt to glue the piece to the existing back, simply place back there and hold it in place with the quarter round you had planned to use for hiding the plywood edges.
Your mitered corners for the quarter round will need to be adjusted (I call it fudged) since the back area is not a nice perfect rectangle.
True the back panel will be free floating but that's nothing new.  An example of free floating is rail and stile type cabinet doors - the panels in them are never glued in place either.
